# Storing data from Nagios into MariaDB using ndoutils-2.0.0

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, nagios, nagiosxi

I am using **ndoutils-2.0.0** for Storing **Nagios** data directory into **MariaDB** Database.

For this I am using the below URL :

http://linuxkarthik.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-install-ndoutils-on-centos.html

In my case **MariaDB database and Nagios in on different Server**.

After all installation and configuration when I restart my ndo2db and nagios service

```
systemctl restart ndo2db.service
systemctl restart nagios.service
```

I got the following Error on Nagios Logs

```
[1482310038] ndomod: NDOMOD 2.0.0 (02-28-2014) Copyright (c) 2009 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
[1482310038] ndomod: I've been compiled with support for revision 402 of the internal Nagios object structures, but the Nagios daemon is currently using revision 403.  I'm going to unload so I don't cause any problems...
[1482310038] Error: Function nebmodule_init() in module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' returned an error.  Module will be unloaded.
[1482310038] Event broker module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' deinitialized successfully.
[1482310038] Error: Failed to load module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o'.
[1482310038] Error: Module loading failed. Aborting.
```

I added the following line into `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg` file

```
broker_module=/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o config_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/ndomod.cfg
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

**I am using CentOS 7, Nagios Core 4.2.2, NDOUtils v2.0.0 and MariaDB-5.5.50.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is upgrade your NDOUtils to version 2.1.0 in order to get it working!

Comment: why I need to upgrade?

Comment: Sorry for typo, I am using MariaDB v5.5.50.

Comment: Because the version of NDO you're using is incompatible with the version of Nagios you're using.

Comment: I am using Nagios Core 4.2.2. So which version of NDOUtils are compatible with Nagios Core 4.2.2.

Comment: Now I am using ndoutils-2.1.2 and when I run make all command it gives the error. "db.c: In function ‘ndo2db_db_init’:
db.c:169:29: error: ‘ndo2db_dbconninfo’ has no member named ‘mysql_conn’
  if(!mysql_init(&idi->dbinfo.mysql_conn))"

Comment: Straight from the help guide: 

`If the configure script is unable to locate your MySQL development libraries,
you may need to help it out by using the --with-mysql-lib or option. Here's an
example:

 ./configure --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql`

Make sure to first install the mariadb development package with I believe: `yum install MariaDB-devel`

Comment: Step 1 : yum install MariaDB-devel Step 2 : ./configure --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib64/mysql Step 3 : make all. Again it gives the same error.

Comment: if you stopped at `make all` then the new broker module didn't get copied to the proper directory. You also need to `make install`. Once that's done, you also need to run the `./installdb` script as indicated in the make output. If you're following the guide you linked to, then your steps will be similar to those ones. However, I just spun up a cent7 vm and got the environment matched to the description you had, and this all worked perfectly for me. The package is all lowercase: `yum install mariadb-devel` I don't know why I capitalized it the way I did.

Comment: Also, I just ran a `make clean`, then `yum remove mariadb-devel`, then tried `make install` again and I get the same error you were getting - so I strongly suspect that its lacking that package. Another thing you might also try is just to `./configure --enable-mysql` it should be able to locate the libraries that way.

Comment: You are right. Step1 : "yum install mariadb-devel" Step2 : "./configure --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib64/mysql" Step3 : "./configure --enable-mysql" Step4 : "make all" Step5 : "make install" Step6 : "change db connection" Than it works for me.